# Extraneous fragment-related code in basic Android app

Tags: android

For learning Android, I've been following examples in a book.  It's been going fine, until a couple days ago I told Eclipse to update itself.  Now when I create a new Android App project, there are two XML files in res/layout/ instead of one.  Also, the java source is different.  Instead of the nice simple (to a tutorial follower) onCreate like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_absolute_lay);
}
```

it is now like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

My question is: what is going on?  The relevant immediate sub-questions are: Did I screw up some default setting in Eclipse, or is this a deliberate change to Android documented somewhere?  Where do I now put my experimental student-quality  and junk - which .xml?   Does code I would normally put in onCreate() now go before or after that fragment-handling business?  Are  we now always having to deal with fragments whereas before is was optional?

Answer (score 1):

> what is going on?

They changed the templates used for the BlankActivity in the Eclipse wizards, and perhaps others.

> Did I screw up some default setting in Eclipse

No.

> is this a deliberate change to Android documented somewhere?

Deliberate? [Yes](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66975). Documented? No.

> Where do I now put my experimental student-quality and junk - which .xml?

That's difficult to answer in the abstract. There's nothing stopping you from deleting those extra lines from `onCreate()` and modifying `activity_main.xml` to contain whatever UI you want in your activity. You can later delete the `PlaceholderFragment` class if you are not using it. Beyond that, without knowing what your "junk" is, we cannot really tell you where to put it.

(IMHO, the bigger problem is that the templates now set up an `ActionBarActivity` with a broken reference to the `appcompat` library project, which is why [I ranted loudly in my own issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67513))

> Does code I would normally put in onCreate() now go before or after that fragment-handling business?

It probably replaces that code. But, again, since we do not know what this code is, we cannot say for certain.

> Are we now always having to deal with fragments whereas before is was optional?

Until such time as they really give us a blank activity template -- no fragments, no AppCompat, etc. -- you will have more stuff to rip out to get to a starting point. Or, you can import [a blank starter project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/releases), but then you need to refactor package names and such.

I certainly encourage you to learn fragments at some point, as they are an important concept in Android UIs. However, I agree that you should not need them for "Hello, world".

Comment: This also explains the mysterious "appcompat" projects appearing out of nowhere.  I was going to ask a separate question about those.

Answer (score 1):

Not idea about what happened in your project. Normally when Eclipse is updated you don't have to be worry for nothing because Eclipse can not change your source files after update it.

Don't worry about the that.

In this peace of code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

when the activity is created, it is loading in one container called R.id.container (if you press ctrl button and click on the top of this R.id.container, Eclipse is going to open the layout file .xml where this component is) one fragment called PlaceholderFragment class.

If you want continuous your work just delete the .xml and .java files that you don't need and overwrite your code with this code. Don't worry about it. copy & paste your code on the top of these one.

For sure when you create a new project, try so see if there is any pre-configuration to create a fragment view or something like that.

If it is not clear for you, ask me.

Comment: It's good to know I can just delete those files and make new ones like from before.  I wasn't sure if that new stuff was in some way required, or fluff I could blow away.